# Leaflet.js setMaxBounds ignores southern bound

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Using [Leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) for an open-source map project, but I need to set specific bounds the user can't move beyond. The maxBounds property of the map object works as expected on the north, east and west directions- but it lets me scroll forever southward.

In the fiddle, the green background reveals where the bound **should** end, and I've added an on-click alert of the latitude for checking.

http://jsfiddle.net/7m7n7/

```
var map = L.map('map', {
maxZoom: 4,
minZoom: 1,
maxBounds: [
    //south west
    [-85.07815906717186, -179.97802734374997],
    //north east
    [-60.413852350464914, 39.8583984375]
]
}).setView([-72.5, -110], 1);

L.tileLayer(
    'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{API}/998/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
    { maxZoom: 18 }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I have no answer, but I did have this discussion the other day in a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558231/leafletjs-setmaxbounds-wont-let-zoom-out-to-see-whole-world/16567244#16567244  The JSFiddle in question has the same problem you did, BUT the problem there was his bounds would let him scroll north forever. South worked just fine. There must be some sort of Leaflet bug in play here.

Comment: Thanks for the lead @PatrickD ! I've reposted my question in the google group for Leaflet (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/leaflet-js/OvVXbJYtkf8) hoping someone's seen it before or brave enough to dig deeper. If I get a solution, will repost here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `setBounds` then leaflet called [`L.Map.panInsideBounds`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v0.5.1/src/map/Map.js#L114) with your bounds, where are you trying get projection: `viewSw = this.project(viewBounds.getSouthWest())`, which use [next code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v0.5.1/src/geo/projection/Projection.SphericalMercator.js#L8) for default projection:

```
project: function (latlng) { // (LatLng) -> Point
    var d = L.LatLng.DEG_TO_RAD,
    max = this.MAX_LATITUDE,
    lat = Math.max(Math.min(max, latlng.lat), -max),
    x = latlng.lng * d,
    y = lat * d;

    y = Math.log(Math.tan((Math.PI / 4) + (y / 2)));

    return new L.Point(x, y);
}
```

So there are `Math.max(Math.min(max, latlng.lat), -max)` can't be more then max or min value and `viewSw` became equal to max value and real bounds not fixed.

This issue [was fixed](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/commit/db6d689ad898caa18cb6db7c6df1632eb6b7114f). You can use [version from master](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/tree/master/dist) or wait when next realise will be come.