# Android Google Maps set maxBounds

Tags: android, google-maps, leaflet, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to restrict the user going beyond the specified city boundary. In leaflet I have achieved this with `maxBounds` property of map object or with `setMaxBounds` function by providing `southwest` & `northeast` points., this way it limits scrolling/zooming beyond that city boundary.

Is there any way like above to restrict scrolling/zooming of Google map in android?

Comment: Have check this SO ticket: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700770/leaflet-js-setmaxbounds-ignores-southern-bound

Comment: @datul, thanks. I need the implementation in android not in leaflet.

Answer (score 5):

The latest version of GoogleMaps has added these features, see the blogpost [here](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ca/2016/08/keep-users-focused-on-whats-important.html). 
In gradle just set: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'` or  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'` depending on which library you're using.

The methods you'll be interested in are:

```
GoogleMap.setMinZoomPreference(float minZoomPreference)
GoogleMap.setMaxZoomPreference(float maxZoomPreference)
GoogleMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(LatLngBounds bounds)
```